# Measuring current from 3V servo

Tags: current-measurement, servo

I am trying to measure the current draw of a 5V analogue hobby servo. I estimate it to be around 100mA. Is it a good idea to use the [ACS712 module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8882)? I'm not sure if my math is correct, but each count the sensor outputs seems to represent 26mA which is relatively large given the 100mA current draw.

Are there other cheap current sensors that give a better sensitivity?

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: 712 is good for 1A to 20A approximately. For 100mA use a resistor and oscilloscope.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Should I use a common 1 ohm carbon film resistor?

Comment: Probably good enough.